# sed or awk script to substitute the structure of a text file

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I want to create a sed or awk script which on `awk -f script.awk oldfile > newfile` turns a given text file `oldfile` with contents

```
Some Heading
example text

Another Heading
1. example list item, but it
spans over multiple lines
2. list item
```

into a new text file `newfile` with contents:

```
{Some Heading:} {example text}

{Another Heading:} {
  [item] example list item, but it spans over multiple lines
  [item] list item
}
```

*Further description to eliminate possible ambiguities*:

- The script should substitute each block (i.e. of lines, encapsulated by blank lines) accordingly.
- In a text file, multiple such blocks may occur and it is not clear in which order they occur.
- The script should do the substitutions conditionally depending on whether a heading (i.e. the first line of a block) is followed by a list of items (indicated by lines beginning with '1.') or not.
- Blocks are always separated by blank lines.

How can I accomplish this with sed or awk? (I use zsh in case this makes a difference.)

---

Addition: I just found out that I really need to know beforehand whether the block is a list or not:

```
heading
1. foo
2. bar
```

to

```
{list: heading}{
 [item] foo
 [item] bar
}
```

So I need to put in the “list:” if it’s a list. Can this also be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is line-oriented and as such is best for simple substitution on a single line.

Just use awk in paragraph mode (`RS=""`) so every block of blank-line-separated text is treated as a record and treat every line in each paragraph as a field of the record (`FS="\n"`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS="\n" }
{
    printf "{" (/\n[0-9]+\./ ? "list: %s" : "%s:") "} {", $1
    inList = 0
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( sub(/^[0-9]+\./,"  [item]",$i) ) {
            printf "\n"
            inList = 1
        }
        else if (inList) {
            printf " "
        }
        printf "%s", $i
    }
    print (inList ? "\n" : "") "}"
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
{Some Heading:} {example text}

{list: Another Heading} {
  [item] example list item, but it spans over multiple lines
  [item] list item
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Notice that it required just the tiniest tweak to check for the existence of a newline followed by a digit in the record when doing the printf of the heading line. I wonder what it'd take in a sed script.... :-). The point is - don't use sed for anything involving processing multiple lines, all of seds arcane language constructs to do that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented, these days people just do it for the challenge, like solving a complex crossword puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

With awk you can do something like this:

```
awk '/^$/ { print block (list ? "\n}" : "}"); block = ""; next } block == "" { block = "{" $0 ":} {"; list = 0; next } /^[0-9]+\. / { list = 1; sub(/^[0-9]+\. /, ""); block = block "\n  [item] " $0; next } { block = block (list ? " " : "") $0 } END { print block (list ? "\n}" : "}") }' filename
```

Where the code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^$/ {                               # empty line: print converted block
  print block (list ? "\n}" : "}")   # Whether there's a newline before the
  block = ""                         # closing } depends on whether this is
  next                               # a list. Reset block buffer.
}
block == "" {                        # in the first line of a block:
  block = "{" $0 ":} {"              # format header
  list = 0                           # reset list flag
  next
}
/^[0-9]+\. / {                       # if a data line opens a list
  list = 1                           # set list flag
  sub(/^[0-9]+\. /, "")              # remove number
  block = block "\n  [item] " $0     # format line
  next
}
{                                    # if it doesn't, just append it. Space
  block = block (list ? " " : "") $0 # inside a list to not fuse words.
}
END {                                # and at the very end, print the last
  print block (list ? "\n}" : "}")   # block
}
```

It is also possible with sed, but rather more difficult to read:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf

/^$/ {                       # empty line: print converted block
  x                          # fetch it from the hold buffer
  s/$/}/                     # append closing }
  /\n  \[item\]/ s/}$/\n}/   # in a list, put in a newline before it
  p                          # print
  d                          # and we're done here. Hold buffer is now empty.
}
x                            # otherwise: inspect the hold buffer
// {                         # if it is empty (reusing last regex)
  x                          # get back the pattern space
  s/.*/{&:}{/                # Format header
  h                          # hold it.
  d                          # we're done here.
}
x                            # otherwise, get back the pattern space
/^[0-9]\+\. / {              # if the line opens a list
  s///                       # remove the number (reusing regex)
  s/.*/  [item] &/           # format the line
  H                          # append it to the hold buffer.
  ${                         # if it is the last line
    s/.*/}/                  # append a closing bracket
    H                        # to the hold buffer
    x                        # swap it with the hold buffer
    p                        # and print that.
  }
  d                          # we're done.
}
                             # otherwise (not opening a list item)
H                            # append line to the hold buffer
x                            # fetch back the hold buffer to work on it

/\n  \[item\]/ {             # if we're in a list
  s/\(.*\)\n/\1 /            # replace the last newline (that we just put there)
                             # with a space
  ${
    s/$/\n}/                 # if this is the last line, append \n}
    p                        # and print
  }
  x                          # put the half-assembled block in the hold buffer
  d                          # and we're done
}
s/\(.*\)\n/\1/               # otherwise (not in a list): just remove the newline
${
  s/$/}/                     # if this is the last line, append closing bracket
  p                          # print
}
x                            # put half-assembled block in the hold buffer.
```

Comment: Loved the understatement `...rather more difficult to read` :-).

Answer (score 1):

Another awk version(similar to Eds)

```
BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n"}
{
    {printf "%s", "{"(/\n[0-9]+\./?"Line: ":"")$1":} {"
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
    printf "%s",sub(/^[0-9]+\./,"  [item]",$i)&&++x?"\n"$i:$i
    print x?"\n}":"}""\n"
    x=0
}
```

---

#### Output

```
$awk -f test.awk file

{Some Heading:} {example text}

{Another Heading:} {
  [item] example list item, but itspans over multiple lines
  [item] list item
}
```

---

#### How it works

```
BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n"}
```

Read Records as blocks separated by a blank line.
Read fields as lines.

```
{printf "%s", "{"(/\n[0-9]+\./?"List: ":"")$1":} {"
```

Print the first field(line) in the format specified, notice printf was used to omit the newline.
Checks if any part of the record contains a newline and then a number and period and adds list if it does.

```
for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
```

Loop from the second field to the last field. `NF` is the number of fields.

I'll split the next bit up.

```
printf "%s"
```

Print a string, printf is used again to control newlines

```
sub(/^[0-9]+\./,"  [item]",$i)&&++x?"\n"$i:$i
```

This is effectively an if else statement using the ternary operator `a?b:c`.
sub will return 0 if it cannot be completed and x will not be incremented so the line will be printed as is.
If the sub is successful,it replaces the number at the start with `[item]` for that line,increments x and prints the new line with a newline before it.

```
print x?"\n}":"}""\n"
```

Uses the ternary operator again to check if x was incremented.If it was prints a newline before the `}` else just rpints the `}`.Prints a newline for the double newline between records.

Comment: remember to reset `x` between records and you need to add a test up front to print `list:` or not.

Comment: @EdMorton Yep missed the x as it only had two line for input thanks! Also didn't see the list

Comment: the 2nd part of their question: `Addition: I just found out...`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It really adds something to the other answers.